# How to say formally if something is "OK"

Tags: word-request

I want to say a sentence like:

> I don't know if you read my message or if it is OK to reply this message, but ...

What are alternative for "if it is OK" to mean almost the same?

Comment: _...if it is alright..._

Comment: I don't understand what you mean my "if it is OK to reply [sic] this message".  Do you mean something like "you are *permitted* to reply to my message" or "it would not be a breach of etiquette/confidentiality/whatever for you to reply to my message"?

Comment: @TRomano yes, it was a bad example, the best interpretation is that  these are two messages (mine and his) in the sentence, *I don't know if you read the message I sent to you or if it is OK to reply this message (the one I am replying)* (because maybe he doesn't want further messages from me, or he won't check the email address by which he sent the message to me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several words could be substituted for *OK*, but it would depend on what you wish to convey.  For example:

> **Permitted**: Having permission to do so
>
> **Allowed**: Permitted by the recipients policy regarding replies
>
> **Proper**: Appropriate given the content of the reply
>
> **Possible**: Indication of a potential *Do Not Reply* status

On the other hand, one can still use *OK* more formally by spelling it out (i.e., *Okay*) instead of using the informal abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on how formal you want it to be. For example, if you want to sound rather formal (but rather stilted), you could write:

> I am not certain whether you have received my message or whether it is acceptable for me to reply this message, but ...